# matching two id variables to a household variable

Tags: r

I have a question regarding merging two id variables using another id variable. As this may sound vague, look at the (sample of) my dataset below

```
Householdid personid    gender      begin_hh    end_hh      typhh
A1             q1       male        19490410    20000101    2
A2             q1       male        20000102    20101010    3
C1             q2       0           19891010    20000101    NA
A2             q2       0           20000102    20101010    3
```

The story behind this dataset could be as follows. Between 1994 and 2000 person q1 lived single and for person q2 the householdstatus is not known. That those two people do not live together is indicated by the householdid variable, which is different and the typehousehold variable which is not equal to 3.  Between 2000 and 2010 both people form a couple, which we can derive from the fact that typehousehold (typhh) is equal to 3 and the fact that the householdid is the same for both persons (i.e. both are indicated by A2). If the householdid would be different, then it would mean they formed a couple with another person.  I would like to transform this dataset into the following:

```
Householdid   personid.male pensionid. female   begin_hh    end_hh      typhh
A1                  q1             NA           19490410    20000101     2
A2                  q1             q2           20000102    20101010     3
C1                  NA             q2           19891010    20000101    NA
```

I tried to use the reshape command, but then in my code it also going to match the personid in the period that both persons were not together (i.e. typhh equal to 2 or NA). Does anyone have any idea how I could get this? I appreciate any help.

Comment: try using `pivot_wider` for example: `pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Householdid, begin_hh, end_hh, typhh), names_from = gender, values_from = personid, names_prefix = "person_")`

Comment: @Ben please consider posting this as an answer, it gives exactly what the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` for what you need.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, 
            id_cols = c(Householdid, begin_hh, end_hh, typhh), 
            names_from = gender, 
            values_from = personid, 
            names_prefix = "person_")
```

where `df` is the data frame to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[gender == 0, gender := "female"], 
    Householdid + begin_hh + end_hh + typhh ~ 
         paste0("person_", gender), value.var = "personid")
#   Householdid begin_hh   end_hh typhh person_female person_male
#1:          A1 19490410 20000101     2          <NA>          q1
#2:          A2 20000102 20101010     3            q2          q1
#3:          C1 19891010 20000101    NA            q2        <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Householdid = c("A1", "A2", "C1", "A2"), personid = c("q1", 
"q1", "q2", "q2"), gender = c("male", "male", "0", "0"), begin_hh = c(19490410L, 
20000102L, 19891010L, 20000102L), end_hh = c(20000101L, 20101010L, 
20000101L, 20101010L), typhh = c(2L, 3L, NA, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```